# How to do swap items in list in a particular way?

Tags: python, list, algorithm, dictionary, logic

```
l = [ 1 ,2 ,3, 4,
      5 ,6 , 7,8,

      9,10,11,12,
      13,14,15,16,

      17,18,19,20,
      21,22,23,24
     ]
```

After swapping in way such that later half of each line is swapped with next line and the process repeats for next two lines:

```
l = [     1 ,2 ,7,8,
          5 ,6 ,3,4,

          9,10,15,16,
          13,14,11,12,

          17,18,23,24,
          21,22,19,20
         ]
```

Case 2: As the rows and columns can vary:

```
  l = [ 1 ,2,
        3, 4,

        5,6, 
        7,8,

        9,10,
        11,12,

         ]
```

Intended Output:

```
l = [   1 ,4,
        3, 2,

        5,8, 
        7,6,

        9,12,
        11,10,

         ]
```

Comment: Did you try anything at all? What issue did you have?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just perform the swaps at the required points. There is a pattern that repeats every 8 positions, and in each of those patterns you swap two pairs:

```
l = list(range(1, 25))
print(l)  # original
for i in range(2, len(l)+1, 8):
    l[i:i+2], l[i+4:i+6] = l[i+4:i+6], l[i:i+2]
print(l)  # swapped
```

If you have a variable `columns` that corresponds to the line breaks you have added to your code, then you can do:

```
half = columns // 2
half3 = half*3
print(l)  # original
for i in range(half, len(l)+1, columns*2):
    l[i:i+half], l[i+columns:i+half3] = l[i+columns:i+half3], l[i:i+half]
print(l)  # swapped
```

This assumes that the length of your list is a multiple of `columns*2`.

Comment: Actually the rows and columns can vary. So hard coding i+2 and i+4 might not work. How can I scale this logic even if rows and columns vary ?

Comment: I have added another case that shows how rows and columns can vary

Comment: But your input has no columns, it is just one row (1-dimensional). Where you insert line breaks, or how many line breaks you insert, has no bearing at all on the data structure. That is just the cosmetic layout you give to your code. Whether you put that list on one line or not, makes no difference to Python.

Comment: Can you clarify how you identify rows and columns (knowing that adding line breaks means nothing to Python)?

Comment: So I am populating this list from a dictionary. And each line in this list is the values associated to a particular key. So I used your logic to make it more scalable like this:  l[i:i+point], l[i+columns: i+(columns+point)] =  l[i+columns: i+(columns+point)],l[i:i+point] . Here point is (columns/2) and columns is the total number of values for any key.

Comment: Indeed that is the principle if you have a variable `columns`. But make sure you adapt the `range` call in the `for` statement as well. See addition to answer.

Comment: Right ,that's what I am doing in for loop. Currently this type of crossover happens in the middle of the column making half=columns/2, Is there anyway to control that through any argument such that the swapping happens at any point in the column as the user wants ?

Comment: Sure that is possible. Did you try it? Please understand that this comment section is not intended for follow-up questions. If you really cannot make it work with a variable "crossover point", then you should ask a new question, and pinpoint where exactly you are stuck in your attempt.

Comment: I have posted as a separate question.  I would really appreciate if you can help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62413589/how-to-swap-items-in-the-list-at-any-point/62413711#62413711

Answer (score 0):

You can slice the list to get all the elements in the same position of the block of 8 (e.g. `l[2::8]` gives you every element on the first row, third column).

```
l = list(range(1, 25))
# Start new list as copy of original
new_list = l.copy()
# Swap third element in row (2nd index)
new_list[2::8] = l[6::8]
new_list[6::8] = l[2::8]
# Similar for fourth element (3rd index)
new_list[3::8] = l[7::8]
new_list[7::8] = l[3::8]
```

This works for any case. The most general way to write this would be something like this:

```
def swap_lines(l, columns_to_swap, row_len):
    """Swap the elements of two different rows in any number of columns.

    Parameters
    ----------
    l : list
        Your list.
    columns_to_swap : list of int
        The indices of the columns to swap.
    row_len : int
        The length of each row
    """
    new_list = l.copy()
    for c in columns_to_swap:
        new_list[c::2*row_len] = l[c+row_len::2*row_len]
        new_list[c+row_len::2*row_len] = l[c::2*row_len]
    return new_list
```

#### Case 1:

```
swap_lines(list(range(1, 25), [2,3], 4)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 7, 8, 
 5, 6, 3, 4, 

 9, 10, 15, 16, 
 13, 14, 11, 12, 

 17, 18, 23, 24, 
 21, 22, 19, 20]
```

#### Case 2

```
swap_lines(list(range(1, 23), [1], 2)
```

Output:

```
[1, 4, 
 3, 2, 

 5, 8, 
 7, 6, 

 9, 12, 
 11, 10]
```