# How to swap items in the list at any point?

Tags: python, list, algorithm, dictionary, data-structures

```
l = [ 1 ,2 ,3, 4,
      5 ,6 , 7,8,

      9,10,11,12,
      13,14,15,16,

      17,18,19,20,
      21,22,23,24
     ]
```

When swapping with next line is done at the middle.
Intended Output:

```
l = [     1 ,2 ,7,8,
          5 ,6 ,3,4,

          9,10,15,16,
          13,14,11,12,

          17,18,23,24,
          21,22,19,20
         ]
```

Working code:

```
n = len(l) #length of list
c = 4 # column length
h =int(c/2)  #middle crossover point 

for i in range(int(c/2) , n+1, int(2*c) ):
    l[i:i+h], l[i+c:i+(c+h)] = l[i+c:i+(c+h)],l[i:i+h]
print (l)
```

Now my code works only when crossover point is middle. I want to scale it to any crossover point . How do I do that ? For ex. if the crossover point is 2nd element , output should be:

```
l = [ 1 ,6,7,8,
      5 ,2,3,4,

      9,14,15,16,
      13,10,11,12,

      17,22,23,24,
      21,18,19,20
     ]
```

Also note that the length of column can be anything , in this example it is 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use in-line swap here. No test for all conditions.

```py
def swap(lst, offset, distance, items):
    for i in range(offset, len(lst)-distance-items+1, 2*distance):
        lst[i:i+items], lst[i+distance:i+distance+items] = (
            lst[i+distance:i+distance+items], lst[i:i+items])

lst = [i+1 for i in range(24)]

swap(lst, 1, 6, 5)  # column offset:1, row length:6, item:5 to swap in-line
```

```
[ 1,  8,  9, 10, 11, 12,
     -------swap--------
  7,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,
 13, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24,
     -------swap--------
 19, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18]
```

```
: Parameters
  lst - list to swap elements
  offset - the start index of elements to swap
  distance - the distance between each start index of elements to swap, you can think it is same as width of total columns.
  items - the number of continue elements to swap
: Return
  None, in-line swap
```

Comment: what do you mean *no test*?

Comment: Four arguments get lot of conditions, it will take much times to find all combination conditions to test. : - )

Comment: the OP's post is supposed to swap 2 columns at once.

Comment: No, you missed it,  another sample 3 columns swapped. The length of column can be anything, no rule for the list dimension, ....

Comment: So distance = offset + items , right ? We can then just use 2 variables instead of 3 def swap(lst, offset, distance, (distance-offset)):

Comment: Added explanation for arguments, for my example swap(lst, 1, 6, 5), it just a chance 6=1+5, It may swap(lst, 1, 6, 1), swap(lst, 1, 6, 2), ..., swap(1, 6, 5).

Comment: For example, swap(lst, 1, 5, 3) means swap index at 1,2,3 with 6, 7, 8; swap 11,12,13 with 16, 17, 18. For a length 24 list, no more swap because not enough elements for next swap.

Comment: @JasonYang Because you didn't add '@AnnZen', I never realized the comment until now I randomly came back. *just saying in case this happens elsewhere and causes misunderstandings*

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do that:

```
a = int(input()) # Swap index
cl = 4 # Amount of columns

l = [1, 2, 3, 4,
     5, 6, 7, 8,
     9, 10, 11, 12,
     13, 14, 15, 16,
     17, 18, 19, 20,
     21, 22, 23, 24]

l2 = l.copy()

for i,v in enumerate(l):
    if i in range(a,len(l),cl*2):
        l2[i] = l[i+cl]
        l2[i+cl] = l[i]
        l2[i+1] = l[i+cl+1]
        l2[i+cl+1] = l[i+1]


print(l2)
```

---

Input:

```
0
```

Output:

```
[5, 6, 3, 4,
 1, 2, 7, 8,
 13, 14, 11, 12,
 9, 10, 15, 16,
 21, 22, 19, 20,
 17, 18, 23, 24]
```

---

Input:

```
1
```

Output:

```
[1, 6, 7, 4,
 5, 2, 3, 8,
 9, 14, 15, 12,
 13, 10, 11, 16,
 17, 22, 23, 20,
 21, 18, 19, 24]
```

---

Input:

```
2
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 7, 8,
 5, 6, 3, 4,
 9, 10, 15, 16,
 13, 14, 11, 12,
 17, 18, 23, 24,
 21, 22, 19, 20]
```

---

Answer (score 0):

```
def swap_lines(l, crossover, row_len):
    """Swap the elements of two different rows in any number of columns.

    Parameters
    ----------
    l : list
        Your list.
    crossover : int
        The first index of the columns to swap.
    row_len : int
        The length of each row
    """
    new_list = l.copy()
    for c in range(crossover, row_len):
        new_list[c::2*row_len] = l[c+row_len::2*row_len]
        new_list[c+row_len::2*row_len] = l[c::2*row_len]
    return new_list
```

This will slice the list to give you every element in the same position of the "block" (e.g. l[2::8] gives you every element on the first row, third column) and swap it with the element in the second row of the block.

Input:

```
swap_lines(list(range(1, 25), 2, 4)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 7, 8, 
 5, 6, 3, 4, 

 9, 10, 15, 16, 
 13, 14, 11, 12, 

 17, 18, 23, 24, 
 21, 22, 19, 20]
```

Comment: Are you sure that is working ? It says ValueError: attempt to assign sequence of size 2 to exntended slice of size 3

Comment: @IshanKumar Good catch! I forgot that the `row_len` is 1-indexed, so it doesn't need another +1. Fixed now.